# Bond intruded into the Atoms in a Chemical structure

Tags: chemfig

I'm using chemfig package for drawing chemical structure. However, in one chemical structure the bond intrudes into the atom. Is there any way to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemname{\chemfig{C*6((-[4]H)-C(-[6]H)=C*6(-C(-[6]H)=C(-[0]H)-C(-[0]H)=C(-[2]H)-)-C=C(-[2]H)-C(-[4]H)=)}}{Naphthalin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“In this case, it is necessary to use two hooks” manual v1.56 p.20

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemname{\chemfig{
    C*6((-[4]H)-C(-[6]H)=C*6(-C(-[6]H)=C(-[0]H)-C(-[0]H)=C?(-[2]H))-C?=C(-[2]H)-C(-[4]H)=)
}}{Naphthalin}

\end{document}
```

[image]